# Get email id on another page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After submit in signup page my signUp page redirects to info.php where I want to collect additional info of user using email id he gives on signup page but when I tried to get the email id of user through sessions, session return empty value.

**THIS IS MY SIGNUP CODE**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name= $_POST['_user'];
        $email = $_POST['_email'];
        $pass = $_POST['_password'];

        //Insert Data

        $sql = "INSERT INTO signup(name,email,password)
                VALUES('$name','$email','$pass')"; 

        //Data Validation

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
            echo "<script>alert('SignUp Successfull')</script>";
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
            header('Location: info.php');

        }
        else{ 
            echo "<script>window.alert('You are already a user.')</script>";
        }

    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

**AND THIS MY INFO.PHP CODE**

```
 <?php
       session_start();
       if(isset($_POST['_submit'])){
           if(empty($_POST['_address']) || empty($_POST['_country']) || empty($_POST['_number']) || empty($_POST['_cnic']) || empty($_POST['_passport'])){
               echo "<script>window.alert('All fields are required')</script>";
           }
           else{
               $address = $_POST['_address'];
               $country = $_POST['_country'];
               $number = $_POST['_number'];
               $cnic = $_POST['_cnic'];
               $passport = $_POST['_passport'];
               $email=$_SESSION['user_email'];


               $query = "INSERT INTO info(email,address,country,mobile,cnic,passport)
                         VALUES('$email','$address','$country','$number','$cnic','$passport')";

               if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
                   header('Location: ../index.php');
               }
               else{ 
                   echo "<script>window.alert('Error While Entering the data!.')</script>";
               }
           }
       }
       mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

In addition I use this global session variable for login page and it works fine.

**UPDATE**
**SIGNUP HTML CODE**

```
<div class="outside">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3 glyphicon glyphicon-user" for="name"></label>
            <div class="control-label col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" name="_user" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">
                <img class="glyphicon1" src="../assests/at-sign.png">
            </label>
            <div class="control-label col-sm-8">
                <input type="email" name="_email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3 glyphicon glyphicon-lock" for="password"></label>
            <div class="control-label col-sm-8">
                <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                <button name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm SignUp</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Already a User? <a href="../login/index.php">LogIn</a></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to see your database connection OR you include any database connection file

Comment: actually I establish a database connection in working files and it works fine

Comment: check email is saved or not in table it may be empty.

Comment: email column is empty

Comment: Post your form code too!!

Comment: @Saty code of both signup and info OR just code of info.php?

Comment: Can't you use [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) right after the insert and instead of `$_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;` store the value of `mysqli_insert_id` in the session?

Comment: The signup form is within the signup php file from above, right?

Comment: I assume, that this `header('Location: info.php');` won't work as you have a echo statement before and probably the entir HTL get's send out before the `header()` statement. `header()` can only be used if *nothing*  has been send to the client before.

Comment: @Mi-Creativity thank you this works.

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped, enjoy coding

Comment: Make sure you don't go live with this code just yet - it is highly unsafe. You have SQL injection vulnerabilities, plaintext passwords and no limit on bruteforce attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Returns the auto generated id used in the last query

```
mysqli_insert_id($link)
```